# How to include calculations in apply or rowsum?

Tags: r, apply

I need to include some operations before summing the rows in my data frame. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  AC1Q = c(0.53, 0.57, 0.60, 0.51), 
  AC4Q = c(0.15, 0.12, 0.09,0.19), 
  AC2Q = c(0.09, 0.05, 0.07, 0.05), 
  AC3Q = c(0.23, 0.26, 0.23, 0.26)
)
df1
#   AC1Q    AC4Q    AC2Q    AC3Q
# 1 0.53    0.15    0.09    0.23
# 2 0.57    0.12    0.05    0.26
# 3 0.60    0.09    0.07    0.23
# 4 0.51    0.19    0.05    0.26
```

I want to get the row sums based on `(sin(2*pi*(AC1Q-0.25)) + sin(2*pi*(-AC4Q+0.25)) - sin(2*pi*(AC2Q+0.25)) - sin(2*pi*(AC3Q-0.25)))/4)` The result should be:

```
# 1 0.20
# 2 0.15
# 3 0.21
# 4 0.10
```

I am learning `apply` and tried `apply(df1, 1, function(x) (sin(2*pi*(df1$AC1Q-0.25)) + sin(2*pi*(-df1$AC4Q+0.25)) - sin(2*pi*(-df1$AC2Q+0.25)) - sin(2*pi*(df1$AC3Q-0.25)))/4)`but the result is wrong. I am not sure what I did wrong. I know I can always do the calculation for each column first, combine them into a data frame, and use `rowsum` But is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: @joel.wilson I tried `apply(x, 1, function(x) (sin(2*pi)*(df1$AC1Q-0.25) + sin(2*pi)*(-df1$AC4Q+0.25) - sin(2*pi)*(-df1$AC2Q+0.25) - sin(2*pi)*(df1$AC3Q-0.25))/4)` but it returns an error message that `object `x` not found`

Comment: how did you get to the expected numbers? is your calculation correct?

Comment: You can use the calculation directly without a loop. Simple use (sin(2*pi)*(df1$AC1Q-0.25) + sin(2*pi)*(-df1$AC4Q+0.25) - sin(2*pi)*(-df1$AC2Q+0.25) - sin(2*pi)*(df1$AC3Q-0.25))/4).                             My question is, sin(2*pi) is almost 0, so how do you get the output that you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x)  (sin(2*pi)*(x["AC1Q"]-0.25) +
                            sin(2*pi)*(-x["AC4Q"]+0.25) - 
                            sin(2*pi)*(-x["AC2Q"]+0.25) - 
                            sin(2*pi)*(x["AC3Q"]-0.25))/4)
```

Comment: this solution gives the exact same answer as `(sin(2*pi)*(AC1Q-0.25) + sin(2*pi)*(-AC4Q+0.25) + (-sin(2*pi)*(-AC2Q+0.25)) + (-sin(2*pi)*(AC3Q-0.25)))/4`, you can even factorize it and end up with `(sin(2*pi) * ( (AC1Q-0.25)+(-AC4Q+0.25) - (-AC2Q+0.25) - (AC3Q-0.25))) / 4`. I don't catch the meaning of using `apply` here.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Sorry that I made a mistake when copying the formula over. The `(ACQ+/-0.25)` should be within `sin` It's corrected now.

Comment: @Jilber my main focus was just to help OP with his solution itself. Just wanted to tell him how to correct his code. And your code is also right.. i fully agree thanks